# IIS Integration testing: remove X-Powered-By: ASP.NET header

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-headers, nant, integration-testing

I want to have a test that testing the inexistent of this http headers, using NAnt and NUnit:

```
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

**Edit:** I'm asking hot to **actually** test this rule: "don't have asp headers". so, I can have this test in each new website that I'm doing, so it make it easier no to forget this simple step.

Comment: And your question is how to remove the headers or how to unit test that?

Comment: I think he wants a test which ensures those headers are not sent.

Comment: I want to have a test, that can be run as part of the build action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make an `HttpWebRequest` to your app then check to see if the response contains those headers.